# Changing standard SP Spinner "working on it" in a Modal Dialog

Tags: 2010, jquery, branding

Im trying to find way to change all standard green spinners in our custom SharePoint 2010 solution to another gif.
I dont want to replace the actuall gif-files in the SharePoint Hive as these will surely be overwritten once we do a CU/PU/SP-update in the future.

My plan is to replace the gifs with jQuery like in this example:

```
jQuery('img[src="/_layouts/images/loadingcirclests16.gif"]').attr({src: "/_layouts/images/NEW_SPINNER.gif"})
```

The problem is that I don't know how to reach the spinner in the Modal Dialog as these don't use code from the normal Master.Pages, where I plan to implement my jQuery. 
How can I reach the code in the standard SharePoint Modal Dialogs? Alternat, how could I better solve this problem?

[image: Working on it...]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A alternate solution is to use CSS instead of jQuery.

To change a standard loading spinners in SharePoint 2010 you could implement css to replace the gif with a different one. The old gif will still load but will be displaced and give room for the new spinner.

```
 [src*='loadingcirclests16.gif']{
      display: block;
      -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      background: url('/_layouts/PORTAL/css/Branding/Icons/news-loader.gif') no-repeat;
      width: 16px; /* Width of new image */
      height: 16px; /* Height of new image */
      padding-left: 16px; /* Equal to width of new image */

}
```